# Issue with Manual unpacking of wars in tomcat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, war

I am unpacking the application war manually in tomcat as I am specifying the context for the application in $CATALINA/conf/Catalina/host/ROOT.xml. The docBase is specified in here,

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Context 
    path="" 
    docBase="/opt/tomcat/tc3/webapps/TC3"
    reloadable="true"
    />
```

When the same war is unpacked by tomcat, i don't see any issues but when I unpack it manually using unzip command, i run into below jasper issue,

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to find taglib "html" for URI: /WEB-INF/struts-html.tld
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:55)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:293)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:80)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:176)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:434)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:492)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1448)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:145)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:244)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:105)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:201)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:372)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:333)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So clearly the issue is because of manual unpacking of war VS the way tomcat unpacks the war. How are WARs unpacked manually or is there a way to make tomcat unpack while specifying the docBase and the context path ?

Comment: The above usually will happen if there is a problem in the appBase/docBase properties relative/absolute to the default values. First remove the context declaration and then directly unzip the war file under webapps/<yourAppName> directory and see if you are still getting the error, it would be best to take a fresh installation of Tomcat.

Comment: I have tried fresh installations to rule out this, but that didn't workout. Between below is my entry in the server.xml ,<Host name="test.com"  appBase="webapps/TC3"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

Comment: When I said clean, please take a stock installation of Tomcat, without modification of any configuration files, in your case the sever.xml is modified.

Comment: The default configuration works out. But my goal is to specify the context path. Either I need to rename the war as ROOT in order to have a default context path or explicitly specify in the conf/Catalina/host/ROOT.xml file. But  i want to stay away from ROOT as my apps name.

Comment: If the manual WAR unpacking under default configuration worksk out, therefore the issue must be the way the appBase/docBase properties are getting configured, take a look at the Tomcat documentation, that would solve the problem https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this working by having different paths for appBase & docBase. docBase contained the path of the directory where my application is manually exploded.

Hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have externalized the manually exploded application. I had kept it in a location /opt/test/TC3 and made the changes in CONFIG_BASE to point the docBase to this location.

But that seems to not solve the issue. Is there a way to autoDeploy while specifying the context ?